# internet blocker for windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, internet, website-blocker

Is there any program for Windows 7 that will give access only for certain web sites. I'm not looking for programs that can block some web sites, but I need program that gives access to only certain web sites user setted up. I just want to give access 1 or 2 web sites, all other web sites should be blocked.

Comment: The thing to Google for is "parental control software" with a *whitelist*.

Comment: Welcome to SoftwareRecs.SE!  We hope you'll like the place and decide to stay.  1.  Why do you want to allow access to only certain websites?  2.  Do you want to restrict yourself, or someone else?  Please [edit] your question and enlighten us.  Each time you edit it, it will be bumped to the top of the homepage, potentially getting it more attention.

Answer (score 3):

I think any firewall should be possible to configure like that. Even Windows firewall can serve well. 
Method is called a WhiteList. Easy principle, you should setup 2 rules:

- one will DENY access for all outgoing IP's on ports 80 and 443.
- one will ALLOW access for address you want to let open.

Carefully, all Widows updates etc. will be blocked as well or you should allow them manually.

Other solution would be to employ some of the parental or security solutions. Serarch for "parental control whitelist" as there is many commercial solutions.